# How does check of authentication work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following line of code in my controller:

```
public function __construct() {
      $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I wish to find out what this line of code does; is it checking before any method in the controller is run that the user is authenticated? I have a little confusion about this line of code; what I want to know is where is this property `middleware` coming form? And how does this this method `middleware` really get included into my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line applies middleware to all controller methods. This particular middleware checks if user is authenticated or not. If user is not authenticated, middleware redirects him to some defined page.

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application.

You can learn more about middleware in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#introduction).

Answer (score 0):

`Middleware`s are listed inside `App/Http/Kernel.php` file. From there you can see that, `auth` uses the `\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` class which checks the request.

Answer (score 0):

`YourController` extends `Controller` class

```
class YourController extends Controller {  }
```

If you navigate to Controller class you can find middleware method and property.

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php
```

`protected $middleware = [];`

```
public function middleware($middleware, array $options = [])
{
    foreach ((array) $middleware as $m) {
        $this->middleware[] = [
            'middleware' => $m,
            'options' => &$options,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` extends `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` class which contains the `middleware` method and property.